# Read in data from .txt file (no header, no separator)

Tags: r, preprocessor

I have a large dataset (~ 200MB) stored in a .txt-file which I need to read into R. Unfortunately there are *no separators* (like " " or ",") between the values of the variables and there is *no header file*.

But there is a codebook, which gives the variable names and also specifies which column belongs to which variable. Some of the variable take one column of space, some take more (so `read.fwf` won't work); but their width is the same for all cases.

I possibly only have to read in a few of these variables, so I expect that I will just have to **select the necessary columns and name the variables**. What would be an elegant solution to do this (and maybe even preselect meaningful variable types)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the type of data that will be read in?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then `read.fwf` should work for you.  Fixed width format means that each variable is assigned a fixed number of columns in the file.  So as long as every value in `Var1` requires ` column and every value in `Var2` requires 3 columns, then `read.fwf` will be able to parse it correctly.

Comment: Adding to @Benjamin's comment: see `?read.fwf`. You can specify the widths for example as follows `read.fwf("file.txt", widths = c(2,4,7,2,6), header=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can consider loading the data as is and then parsing each line using '`strsplit`' with appropriate regular expression.

```
con <- file("yourfile.txt", open = "r")
lines <- readLines(con)
```

Iterate it over, apply `strsplit` to each line and add that to your data table with `rbind`.